# NodeJS Async Await Undefined Response

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am trying to use `async/await` to wait for a request to complete and return some information before I proceed with the rest of my code. The function logs the correct response, but the `await` line says it received an `undefined` value. This is the function I am calling, which logs the correct response here `console.log(loginResponse.idToken);`

However, this line `let newtoken = await AuthHelper.returnValidToken(token)` logs an `undefined` instead of the response. What mistake am I making here?

```
    returnValidToken: async (token) => {
    await AuthHelper.msal
      .acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest)
      .then((loginResponse) => {
        AuthHelper.decodedValidToken(
          loginResponse.idToken.rawIdToken,
          key,
          (jsonToken) => {           

            if (jsonToken.result === "success") {
              // debugger;
              console.log(loginResponse.idToken);
              return (loginResponse.idToken);
            }
          }
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  },
```

Comment: why is there an await and a then function for a AuthHelper.msal.acquireTokenSilent use one of them

Comment: You don't return anything from `.then`, so the promise chain resolves to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the code to use async/await completely

```js
 returnValidToken: async (token) => {
   try{
    const loginResponse = await AuthHelper.msal.acquireTokenSilent(loginRequest);
    const jsonToken = await AuthHelper.decodedValidToken(loginResponse.idToken.rawIdToken,key)

    if (jsonToken.result === "success") {
              console.log(loginResponse.idToken);
              return (loginResponse.idToken);
    }
    }
    catch(e){
     console.log(e)
     return null;
    }
  },
```

This is assuming that the `AuthHelper.decodedValidToken` is also `async`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this, you should be using either async/await - or Promise.then().

But not both.

Comment: True and I was about to write the same but this is not an answer - it's a comment!

Comment: Although it's generally clearer to stick to one or the other, they're entirely interoperable. The problem is mixing promises (whether `async`/`await` or `.then`) with _callbacks_.

Comment: refactoring the Promise.then into an async/await fixed my issue. I cant believe i didnt think of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that changing the style from a mix of async/await with then didn't work.
The problem is that you're missing a `return` before `AuthHelper.decodedValidToken`.

That said, I totally agree that you should choose one style (preferably async/await) and stick to it.